# Is Kotlin synchronized() not locking basic types?

Tags: kotlin

```
class Notification(val context: Context, title: String, message: String) {
    private val channelID = "TestMessages"

    companion object ID {
        var s_notificationID = -1
    }

    init {
        var notificationID = -1
        synchronized(s_notificationID) {
            if (++s_notificationID == 0)
                createNotificationChannel()
            notificationID = s_notificationID
        }
```

The above is being called simultaneously from two threads. A breakpoint in `createNotificationChannel()` clearly showed that sometimes `s_notificationID` equals 1.

However, if I change
`synchronized(s_notificationID)`
to `synchronized(ID)`
then it seems to lock fine.

Is synchronized() not locking basic types? And if so, why does it compile?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A look at the generated JVM bytecode indicates that the `ID` example looks like

```
synchronized(ID) { ... }
```

which is what you'd expect. However, the `s_notificationID` example looks more like

```
synchronized(Integer.valueOf(s_notificationID)) { ... }
```

In Java, we can only synchronize on objects, not on primitives. Kotlin mostly removes this distinction, but it looks like you've found one place where the implementation still seeps through. Since `s_notificationID` is an `int` as far as the JVM is concerned (hence, not an object) but `synchronized` expects an object, Kotlin is "smart" enough to wrap the value in `Integer.valueOf` on demand. Unfortunately for you, that produces wildly inconsistent results, [because](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int))

> This method will always cache values in the range -128 to 127, inclusive, and may cache other values outside of this range.

So for small numbers, this is guaranteed to lock on some cached object in memory that you don't control. For large ones, it may be a fresh object (hence always unlocked) or it might again end up on a cached object out of your hands.

The lesson here, it seems, is: Don't synchronize on primitive types.

Comment: Thank you. Then this is either a Kotlin implementation bug, or Kotlin undocumented "feature" that should issue compilation error/warning. Where can it be reported?

Answer (score 5):

Silvio Mayolo explained why it is not a good idea to synchronize on primitives (actually, I think the compiler should warn about this). But I believe there is another problem with this code, probably the main one that makes your `synchronized` blocks work in parallel.

The problem is that you replace the value of `s_notificationID`. Even if it would be an object, not a primitive, your synchronized blocks would still run in parallel, because each call to `synchronized` uses a different object. This is why in Java we usually synchronize on `this` and not on a field that we need to modify.

Comment: Often times Java code synchronizes on a private _final_ `Object` field. It can potentially lead to problems synchronizing on `this` because then external code (external to the class) can uncontrollably obtain the lock. Because of that, synchronizing on `this` effectively becomes public API which one may not want nor intend.

Comment: Thank you. I think your answers are actually pointing to the same problem. Kotlin makes us imagine Int as an object with operator ++ which modifies its content,  while actually it is implemented in a way that ++ gives a new value, or in other words "replacing" the object.

Comment: Actually, Java does exactly the same. If you create an `Integer foo` field (not `int`) then you can perform `foo++`, but this is really compiled to: `foo = foo + 1`. Primitive wrappers are immutable, so it can't be done differently. On the other hand, real primitives don't have an identity, so replacing and mutating is the same thing.

Comment: @broot Even so, I had higher expectation from Kotlin. From [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html): In Kotlin, everything is an object in the sense that we can call member functions and properties on any variable. Some types can have a special internal representation - for example, numbers, characters and booleans can be represented as primitive values at runtime - but to the user they look like ordinary classes. In this section we describe the basic types used in Kotlin: numbers, booleans, characters, strings, and arrays.

Comment: I'm not sure if I read you correctly, but this is not really the problem with primitives or their internal representation in Kotlin. You would have exactly the same problems if using Java and synchronizing on an Integer object. This is probably why nobody does this in Java ;-) The real problem here is that we should not synchronize on objects that we don't really "own". And while primitive objects are cached, we don't own them. Also, usually we should not synchronize on var/non-final fields. Actually, Java shows a warning when doing this. I guess Kotlin should do the same.

Comment: @DoronBen-Ari Note that the `++` operator in Kotlin [is expected to return a new object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#increments-and-decrements). For `Int` specifically: Although it may be considered an object in Kotlin that doesn't mean it's not _immutable_.

Comment: @Slaw Of course a++ returns a new object, because it needs to have the previous value.  But ++a does not need to do that, because it returns the new value. Anyhow, what you mention is about the return value of ++, while what is relevant to the subject is wether ++ mutates the Int "object" or replaces it.

Comment: @DoronBen-Ari "_Anyhow, what you mention is about the return value of ++, while what is relevant to the subject is wether [sic] ++ mutates the Int "object" or replaces it_" – That's a distinction without a difference. And that documentation is for both `a++` and `++a`. They should not mutate the object.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** The lesson here, it seems, is: Don't synchronize on primitive types.

`synchronized(i)` where `i` is `Int`, is actually `synchronized(Integer.valueOf(i))`.
Only in the range -128 to 127 this value is guaranteed to be a cached value.
Another fact is that `++i` cannot be looked at as a mutation of the "object" `i`, but rather as replacing `i` by a new "object" with the value `i+1`.

Thank you *broot* & *Silvio Mayolo* for the above.

Experiments I did prove the above.
In my original code I have removed the `++` from
`++s_notificationID`. Amazingly or not, the lock worked now.
Now with that change I changed `var s_notificationID = -1` to be `var s_notificationID = -1000`. Even more amazing, now the lock again stopped working.

Still, I think this anomaly of basic types undermines the attempt of Kotlin to see basic types as objects, and I think this should have been mentioned clearly in Kotlin documentation.